# The type of positioning is really affecting my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, position

I'm currently making a drag-and-drop JavaScript engine. I'm currently making a "bounding" feature, so that the drag-object is bounded by a container with the class `.bound`. When I make the drag-object, I also find out if it has bounds:

```
function makeObj(e) {
    obj = new Object();
    obj.element = e;

    obj.boundX = e.parentNode.offsetWidth - e.offsetWidth;
    obj.boundY = e.parentNode.offsetHeight - e.offsetHeight;

    obj.posX = event.clientX - e.offsetLeft;
    obj.posY = event.clientY - e.offsetTop;

    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (e.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += e.offsetLeft;
            curtop += e.offsetTop;
            //alert(e.id + ":" + e.innerHTML);
            if(~e.className.search(/bound/)) {
                obj.boundX = curleft - obj.element.offsetLeft;
                obj.boundY = curtop - obj.element.offsetTop;
                return obj;
            }

        } while (e = e.offsetParent);
    }

    return obj;
}
```

My loops work, however setting the bounds does not.

I would like this html to affect the function:

```
<div id="center" class="bound">
    <h1>Hello World! <hr /></h1>
    <div id="box" class="bound">
        <p class="drag square" id="one"> One </p>
        <p class="drag square" id="two"> Two </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As much as this html:

```
<div id="center"> <!-- Difference is here -->
    <h1>Hello World! <hr /></h1>
    <div id="box" class="bound">
        <p class="drag square" id="one"> One </p>
        <p class="drag square" id="two"> Two </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The difference is the `.bound` class, which has `position: relative` set.

Here is the CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}    

.drag {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.bound {
    position: relative;
}

.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    cursor:move;
}

#center {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
}

#box {
    background-color: #FF3;
    height: 278px;
    border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**How do I make it so the `position:` attribute doesn't affect how the engine works- So that any position will work. Absolute, Relative, Static, ect? How can I make my `.drag` objects have any kind of positioning besides absolute?**

I will post the entire engine below (and a jsfiddle link) just in case it is useful:

http://jsfiddle.net/Upvdm/1/

```
// JavaScript Document

var dragObj;

document.addEventListener("mousedown", down, false);

function down(event) {
    if(~event.target.className.search(/drag/)) {
        dragObj = makeObj(event.target);
        dragObj.element.style.zIndex="100";
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", freeMovement, false);
    }
}

function freeMovement(event) {

    if (typeof(dragObj.element.mouseup) == "undefined")
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
    //Prevents redundantly adding the same event handler repeatedly

dragObj.element.style.left = Math.max(0, Math.min(event.clientX - dragObj.posX, dragObj.boundX)) + "px";
    dragObj.element.style.top = Math.max(0, Math.min(event.clientY - dragObj.posY, dragObj.boundY)) + "px";
}

function drop() {
    dragObj.element.style.zIndex="1";

    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", freeMovement, false);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
    //alert("DEBUG_DROP");
}

function makeBoundlessObj(e) {
    obj = new Object();
    obj.element = e;

    obj.boundX = e.parentNode.offsetWidth - e.offsetWidth;
    obj.boundY = e.parentNode.offsetHeight - e.offsetHeight;

    obj.posX = event.clientX - e.offsetLeft;
    obj.posY = event.clientY - e.offsetTop;

    return obj;
}

function makeObj(e) {
    obj = new Object();
    obj.element = e;

    obj.boundX = e.parentNode.offsetWidth - e.offsetWidth;
    obj.boundY = e.parentNode.offsetHeight - e.offsetHeight;

    obj.posX = event.clientX - e.offsetLeft;
    obj.posY = event.clientY - e.offsetTop;

    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (e.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += e.offsetLeft;
            curtop += e.offsetTop;
            //alert(e.id + ":" + e.innerHTML);
            if(~e.className.search(/bound/)) {
                obj.boundX = curleft - obj.element.offsetLeft;
                obj.boundY = curtop - obj.element.offsetTop;
                return obj;
            }

        } while (e = e.offsetParent);
    }

    return obj;
}

function findPos(obj) { // Donated by `lwburk` on StackOverflow
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for reading and helping!

Comment: Not to be that guy, but don't reinvent the wheel unless you're trying to learn something: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: learning about wheels eh?
In your `makeObj` function you use `event` which hasn't been passed in and so is undefined

Comment: @Tom, thanks for being "that guy" - it shows that you do care about helping. However, this is my first week of JavaScript (ever), so I'm trying to learn the language before I jump into libraries!

Comment: @meouw you're right. Should I add another parameter and stick event in it? Nevertheless, it still seems to work...

Answer (score -1):

```
while (e = e.offsetParent);
```

Should be

```
while (e == e.offsetParent); //alternatively, use ===
```

In C-like languages (like JavaScript), = means "Put the value of the variable on the right to the variable on the left." However, == means "Do the values on both sides match?"

JavaScript considers anything but a few things (like 0, an empty string, null and undefined) as false and everything else as true. So, the expression `e = e.offsetParent` will always return true.
Tested it and it works on the JSFiddle example you sent.

Comment: Actually I think he may want "=" there, because he's walking up the chain of "offsetParent" elements. He wants it to be an assignment to update "e", and also to serve as a termination condition when there is no offset parent (that is, when `e.offsetParent` is null).

Comment: no, `while (e = e.offsetParent)` is correct here. `e` is being set to the `offsetParent` until `offsetParent` is `undefined`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but e doesn't change inside the while statement, so it remains the same, and so does the offsetParent.

Comment: It sure will change, @Zirak, when the expression "e = e.offsetParent" is evaluated :-)

Comment: *facepalm* duh. Sorry about that...now it makes me even more wonder why changing it makes it work.

Comment: @Zirak well I got sort-of a headache trying to read all that code, but it could be that you're actually right, but for the wrong reason :-)  Maybe the process of figuring out the "chain" of offset parents is a bad idea?

Comment: @Pointy don't get a headache! I know it's a lot of code which makes me fear people are going to skip over it because they don't wish to read it all, but I'll never figure this one out on my own =/

Comment: @Zirak and @Pointy, it does work, and I can tell you why. A do while loop executes once even if the initial condition is false (which it clearly is). So the `obj.boundX` and `obj.boundY` aren't being changed in the loop. If you look at the entire function, however, you will see I gave them values before entering the loop in case they are "boundless"- or none of the parents have the `.bound` class. I set the values of the `boundX` and `boundY` to the bounds of the parent element before entering the loops. I plan on changing that after I get the loops working.