# How do I make all of the position attributes the same?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a drag-and-drop engine in JavaScript, and I'm currently adding a "bounding" feature. My issue is that the bounding element's position changes depending on its parent's `position:` attribute.

In other words this html:

```
<div id="center" class="bound">
    <h1>Hello World! <hr /></h1>
    <div id="box" class="bound">
        <p class="drag square" id="one"> One </p>
        <p class="drag square" id="two"> Two </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this html:

```
<div id="center"> <!-- Difference is here -->
    <h1>Hello World! <hr /></h1>
    <div id="box" class="bound">
        <p class="drag square" id="one"> One </p>
        <p class="drag square" id="two"> Two </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

affect the engine in different ways, and they shouldn't. Only the `<div id="box" class="bound">` should affect the drag object.

Here is the CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}    

.drag {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.bound {
    position: relative;
}

.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    cursor:move;
}

#center {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
}

#box {
    background-color: #FF3;
    height: 278px;
    border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

If anyone asks for the JavaScript function which sets the bounding, I will be happy to post it in an edit!

**To make the position attribute not affect my JavaScript would I need to translate everything into absolute coordinates? How would I do this? Will translating everything into absolute coordinates allow the JavaScript to treat the two html samples the same way?**

Comment: Didn't you [just ask this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134140/the-type-of-positioning-is-really-affecting-my-javascript)?

Comment: @patrick It's a slightly different question. My last question was double sided and was really more about the `.drag` object (even though it didn't get a lot of attention). This question is focussed around the `.bound` class (and not the loops aspect of correctly setting the boundary which the last post was about). I was planning on making another question later specifically about the drag-object. This question is about how to (specifically) make the `position` attribute not affect anything else.

Comment: I'll take your word that this is a different issue. Just be aware that you shouldn't re-post the same question. You can edit it to provide more info, which may help attract some attention. You can also place a "bounty" on the question after 2 days in order to motivate others to take a closer look.

Comment: @patrick Yeah, I'm not very good at explaining things sometimes, so I thought it would be better to split the issue into different sub-topics because the focus on my last question was how to place the `.drag` object, which isn't as important as creating the correct boundary (which this question is trying to answer). I'll make sure to set a bounty if I my questions are unanswered. Thanks for the advice- setting one never really occurred to me.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, to drag and drop, the element must have the position property as `absolute` or `fixed`.

And of course its position will change when you change the position property.

Comment: Can I write JavaScript to allow the position property to be any value? Not just `absolute` or `fixed`?

Comment: No, @Dbz, you cannot override the semantics of the "position" style with JavaScript.  You can *change* the "position" style from "absolute" to "relative" or whatever, but you cannot tell the browser to stop paying attention to it.

Comment: @Pointy rather than tell the browser to stop paying attention to it, can I figure out what the position value is, and translate that into `absolute` type coordinates?

Comment: I'm going to edit the original question to ask how to do that